# Python round scientific notation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a value:

```
1.9675925925925927e-07
```

And I am getting this value by subtracting the Datetime and I only want 1.967 or 1.9.

For that I looked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34032855/rounding-scientific-notation-in-python) and here I have used:

```
def precision_round(number, digits=3):
    power = "{:e}".format(number).split('e')[1]
    return round(number, -(int(power) - digits))
```

I am using this:

```
x = 1.9675925925925927e-07
print("Round",precision_round(x, digits=3))
#OUTPUT: Round 1.968e-07
```

So my question is what is the best way to remove those values. and round it like 1.96. Since this value is a result of:

```
((df['nextUpdatedAt'] - df['updatedAt']).dt.total_seconds() / 3600 / 24)
```

Where date format is:

```
2021-03-25 10:27:45.099
```

And I am using pandas formula.

Comment: there might be better ways but `(df['delta'].dt.total_seconds() / 3600 / 24).astype(str).str.slice(stop=4).astype(float)`

Comment: you're not talking about rounding it sounds like - you'd like to remove the exponent?