# How to reduce the number of zeros after the decimal place when printing NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following situation:

```
import numpy as np:

V = np.ones((12, 12))
V[1][5] = 123523.42341234
print(np.round(V[0], 3))
print(np.round(V, 3))
```

The first print gives: `[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]` which is what I want. However, the second one gives:

```
[[1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
 [1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.23523423e+05 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
 [1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
 [1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
 [1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
 [1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
 [1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
 [1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
 [1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
 [1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
 [1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
 [1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]
```

which makes it very difficult to read (in practice I have more entries that are not one). For now I just need it for display purposes, so I would like to have the "1.00000000e+00" printed as "1" only. How can I do that?

Comment: Note that you get a similar problem with `np.round(V[1],3)`. It happens whenever the array contains `123523.42341234`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34032855/rounding-scientific-notation-in-python

Comment: Please read the tags before using them. [decimalformat] is a tag for a Java class of the same name.

Comment: Tag [tag:number-formatting].

Comment: To give a qualified answer one has to know what you want to have displayed for you special entry. Is `1.23e5` ok, 123523.42`, or do you need full precision?